# How to paste images in Chrome? (By default it pastes the URL)

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, mac

If I right click an image in Chrome and select "copy image", and then paste it in Gmail it pastes the URL. If I paste elsewhere, e.g., in GDocs or a desktop app it pastes the image.

(Googling turns up much discussion, but only ugly & indirect solutions which generally work by pasting somewhere else and then re-copying. I'm using the latest Mac version of Chrome.)

Answer (score 1):

Either copy the image itself or use the "Insert photo" tool to paste the image from the URL.

[image: compose window with "insert photo" icon circled]

[image: "insert photo" dialog with "insert by web address (URL)" tab active]